# What are the best resources for learning music theory that mesh with Overtone's theory-related facilities?

Tags: clojure, overtone

I'm not much of a musician (witness my mostly-unsuccessful interludes with guitars and pianos), but I find myself able to produce reasonably pleasant sound via [Overtone](http://overtone.github.io/), and have a great time doing so.  (As Sam Aaron has said, it's a great way to translate programming ability into musicality, which seems to have been borne out to some extent.)

My question is, Overtone provides a variety of music theory-related devices (e.g. scales, metronomes, etc) in [`overtone.music.*`](https://github.com/overtone/overtone/blob/master/src/overtone/music/), which I've tinkered with but simply don't understand fundamentally.  I wonder if anyone could recommend a reasonably approachable music theory book / guide / resource that would mesh well with the facilities that Overtone provides?

Comment: This is obviously off-topic, but I have favorited it rather than voting to close. That's what you get when you let the whacky community with all their side interests run the show. But try http://music.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 11):

Let me answer from the synthesis perspective - which is one of my main interests. Learning to design new synthesisers is a pretty dark art, and most of the books/resources I found take a very theory-centric stance which I found to not be particularly useful.

However, I have found the following practical guides extremely valuable:

- The SOS Synth Secrets articles: http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/allsynthsecrets.htm
- The book Steal This Sound [http://www.amazon.com/Keyboard-Presents-Steal-This-Sound/dp/1423492811](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1423492811)
- The software Syntorial: http://syntorial.com

Each of these has a slightly different take on walking you through the practicalities of synthesis design inviting you to actually build your own, experiment and play.

Comment: Syntorial looks pretty great, very immediate feedback about e.g. ugens I can plug around in Overtone.  If only there were two modes: one using the graphical "patch" metaphor, the other using a 4Clojure-style programming environment to coax you towards the "correct" impl of a synth in Overtone. ;-)

Comment: After plinking around with those resources — all of them good — I think I'm looking more for something that will help me understand the core _music_ theory bits, esp. [`overtone.music.pitch`](https://github.com/overtone/overtone/blob/master/src/overtone/music/pitch.clj) (and really, all the stuff that's in / planned for `overtone.music.*`).  Maybe that means I should just "go google for a fundamental music theory text", but I'd like to stay as close to overtone as possible when learning, since it's effectively my instrument. 'Learning Music Theory w/ Overtone' sounds like a good book title. :D